# How to set the background of a CALayer to be transparent without affecting the borders?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, calayer, nsview

I have a `layer-backed NSView` in my `Cocoa` application. Using the following code the **entire** custom view is made transparent:

```
    self.layer?.opaque = false
    self.layer?.opacity = 0
```

Unfortunately, I need the border of the `CALayer` to remain visible (and currently it is being made transparent). How best do I go about getting only the border to show?

## EDIT

I have now managed to get it working but I am unsure as to why.

I didn't think it was relevant previously but The `layer backed NSView` is actually an `NSTextField`. This exposes a backgroundColor field that seems to "have more influence" than that of the `CALayer`

setting `self.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor()` has done the job.

However, I have opted into layers by

1. Setting `self.wantsLayer = true`
2. Overriding `wantsUpdateLayer` and returning true
3. The code manipulating the layers was in my `updateLayer()` method

The question now is why the above works and *NOT* using `clearColor` on the `CALayer`?

Comment: So you need the border to be an outline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## FINDINGS

The fact that it is a `layer-backed NSTextField` as opposed to a regular `layer-backed NSView` appears to be important... it has its own background that will appear *in front* of the layer's background unless you set the following:

```
self.drawsBackground = false
```

If you do that, then you can indeed use the `NSColor.clearColor().CGColor` as the layer's backgroundColor.

If you don't, then it looks like you need to set the backgroundColor of your view directly to control the background.

Answer (score 6):

How about setting the layer background to the clear color?

```
self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor().CGColor
```

I don't think you even need to set `opaque` and `opacity`. I would remove those lines.

Comment: I tried that (and I tried it again to make sure) but it just makes it effectively white and I am not able to see through to what is behind this layer-backed view.

Comment: I have worked through this in more detail - see my findings posted in the question. Does that agree with your experience?